# Error starting R-studio for the first time

Tags: installation, rstudio

I am having the following problem when starting R-studio...

```
Error installing package: `* installing *source* package 'rstudio'` ...

** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded

ERROR: loading failed
* removing `'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/rstudio'`

Error installing package: * installing *source* package `'manipulate'` ...

** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
ERROR: loading failed

* removing `'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/manipulate'`
```

It has been treated here in before but it references to network problems. 
This is a personal laptop. Thank you for any inputs you may have. I am not a programmer savy. 
So, I will appreciate any answers taking this matter into consideration. Thank you again!!
Mariano.

Comment: Try installing R in a folder you have write permissions for (e.g. `C:/R-3.1.2`).

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. The problem is not with R. In fact, Ri386 3.1.2 runs without problems. The issue is with R-Studio. In fact, R is installed under C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2. Do you see any problems with this? Thank you!

Comment: By the way, it didn´t work Kevin (the uninstall plus the install into C directly). Thanks anyway. Any help on this matter will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Right -- it just appears that the problem is RStudio doesn't have permissions to write out to these folders (it attempts to install the R packages `rstudio` and `manipulate` on startup). You could also try starting RStudio with admin privileges, or checking how it was installed (e.g. install it with an account that has more write privileges)

Comment: Kevin, thank you for your reply. Problem solved. Somehow it didn´t work automatically. I had to locate the files manipulate and rstudio separately and work them manually with...
install.packages("C:/Documents and Settings/Perla/Desktop/manipulate.zip", repos=NULL)
install.packages("C:/Documents and Settings/Perla/Desktop/rstudio.zip", repos=NULL)
Doing it this way, Rstudio starts now with no error messages.
Thank you all for your help! 
Mariano.

Answer (score 0):

I literately tried every method I found online (through some of them I don't quite understand), including checking lib path, removing extra lib path, creating environment variable as R_LIBS. I am very sure I have encounter the UNC problem.

Here is the solution I used:

1. Go to C:\Program Files\RStudio\R\library
   (or the equivalent folder from your RStudio install). Copy the folders 'manipulate' and 'rstudio' located here.
2. Paste them to the folder that R is trying to find them, and : 
   Z:\R\win-library\3.1 (Note: Z: is the network drive.)

In your case, you should paste them in this folder 
C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/

(if there are already a manipulate and an rstudio folder in your R\Library folder, make sure you delete those first).

This solved everything!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and solved it a different way.  Sadly, I run a Windows 7 machine and receive more errors than a modern-day computer should allow.  I have used rstudio many times but usually not on my personal computer.  When I updated my PC, I started to receive that same error and also when installing packages.

The problem I had was that my username contained a ' .  The single quote was also in the User/Username folder directory.

To remedy this, I had to create an alternate user for my own computer, set it as administrator, reboot in safe mode, rename the file directory, change my registry, and make a few other changes.  When I was done, the error did not appear anymore.  Detailed steps [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/147545-user-profile-folder-change-user-account-folder-name.html)

I am also now more seriously considering purchasing a Mac.